# Not getting timezone while posting JSON on server

Tags: php, json

I have problem regarding the JSON post. Below is my json format.

```
{
  "wakeuptime_activity":
   [{
    "sActivity":"Asdfdsa",
    "dDateTime":"2012-10-12",
    "nWakeupDuration":"1",
    "sWakeupTime":"2012-10-12 11:59:00 PM+0530"
   }]
}
```

When I am posting this json on server and decode this json using php function json_decode(), I am getting sWakeupTime field value as "2012-10-12 11:59:00 PM 0530" without "+"

It would be nice if anyone told me that what i am doing wrong in json string?

Answer (score 0):

You've got to escape your string.

Use `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
...
sWakeupTime: encodeURIComponent(sWakeupTime)
...
```